# Firemonkey forms opened with TForm.Show are get hiden when OnClick of the main form is performed

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

When a form is opened with TForm.Show, and you click outside of this form, it will hide. On the VCL it doesn't happens.

I could use the property FormStyle set to StayOnTop, but it would not be good for the kind of application i'm building.

What could i do to solve this?

Comment: I did remember one more thing: a can not open this form whti TForm.ShowModal, because i want to be able to do other things on the application when a form is visible.

Comment: Does it actually hide, or drop behind your main window. When you click outside, as you put it, focus is moved elsewhere.

Comment: Great observation!
Actually the focus change to the main form, and the second form hide behind my main form.
Is it possible to click on the main form, and the focus continue to change, but the second form don't hide?

Answer (score 1):

I had to set the Parent of the second form. Just like this:

```
SecondForm.Parent := MainForm;
```

Doing this, when you click on the MainForm, the focus is changed, but the second form doesn't hide behind the MainForm.